Cannot get tables to be formatted as tables in Discussions
Table markdown is not supported in Discussions.
Here's an example:

Have a singe "Report" table



reportedEntityId
reportedEntityType




1
Post


2
Post


2
Comment







As shown above, while the copied text here on Meta is formatted as a table, it is not on Discussions.

Does discussions use the new editor?

It's interesting the editor for the Discussion doesn't even have the table icon in the editor bar, but the Stacks Editor in the replies do have the table icon and do support tables. I agree it's a bug that tables would be supported only in replies and not the discussion itself.

@TylerH yes, it does.

Thank you for the bug report. Table markdown can now be previewed on the Stacks Editor when creating/editing discussions.

Thank you, Tobi. I have confirmed this.

On another note, can I have an extra rep like you do? :)
